# Prove integral limit exists $\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\int\limits_0^1\frac{dx}{(x^4+t^4)^{1/4}}+\ln t$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Prove integral limit exists

$$\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\left(\int\limits_0^1\frac{dx}{(x^4+t^4)^{1/4}}+\ln t\right)$$
I try to change variable $u=1/x$ then $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1\frac{dx}{(x^4+t^4)^{1/4}}=\frac{1}{4}\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{4u^3du}{u^4(1+u^4x^4)^{1/4}}$.

But I have no idea to continue.

Comment: For every $t$, $$I(t)=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(x^4+t^4)^{1/4}}+\ln t=\int_0^{1/t}\frac{dx}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}}-\int_1^{1/t}\frac{dx}x$$ hence $$\lim_{t\to0}I(t)=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(x^4+1)^{1/4}}-\int_1^\infty\left(\frac1x-\frac1{(x^4+1)^{1/4}}\right)dx$$

Comment: Equivalently, $$\lim_{t\to0}I(t)=\int_1^\infty\frac{1+x-(x^4+1)^{1/4}}{x(x^4+1)^{1/4}}dx$$

Comment: It seems to be more complicated than the first one.

Comment: Sorry but didn't you ask for the convergence? My first comment proves it, if you do not like the explicit formula of the limit in the second comment, just forget it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral can be solved using the substitution $u=\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{x^4+t^4}}{x}$ and some algebra maneuvering to obtain the general result $$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left(\left\vert\sqrt[4]{x^4+t^4}+x\right\vert\right)-\ln\left(\left\vert\sqrt[4]{x^4+t^4}-x\right\vert\right)-2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{x^4+t^4}}{x}\right)\right]\bigg\vert_{0}^{1}+\ln(t)$$ $$=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln(\sqrt[4]{t^4+1}+1)-\ln\vert\sqrt[4]{t^4+1}-1\vert-2\arctan(\sqrt[4]{t^4+1})-\ln(t)+\ln(t)+2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right]+\ln(t)$$ $$=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left\vert\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{t^4+1}+1}{\sqrt[4]{t^4+1}-1}\right\vert+\frac{\pi}{2}\right]+\ln(t)=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left\vert t^4\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{t^4+1}+1}{\sqrt[4]{t^4+1}-1}\right\vert\right]+\frac{\pi}{8}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left\vert \dfrac{\sqrt[4]{t^{20}+t^{16}}+t^4}{\sqrt[4]{t^4+1}-1}\right\vert\right]+\frac{\pi}{8}\to\dfrac{0}{0}\xrightarrow{\text{L'Hopital}}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left\vert \dfrac{\frac{1}{4}\left(t^{20}+t^{16}\right)^{-\frac{3}{4}}\cdot \left(20t^{19}+16t^{15}\right)+4t^3}{\frac{1}{4}\left(t^4+1\right)^{-\frac{3}{4}}\cdot 4t^3}\right\vert\right]+\frac{\pi}{8}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left\vert \dfrac{\frac{1}{4}\left(t^{20}+t^{16}\right)^{-\frac{3}{4}}\cdot \left(20t^{16}+16t^{12}\right)+4}{\left(t^4+1\right)^{-\frac{3}{4}}}\right\vert\right]+\frac{\pi}{8}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left\vert \dfrac{\frac{1}{4}\left(20t^{16}+16t^{12}\right)+4}{t^{12}}\right\vert\right]+\frac{\pi}{8}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left\vert\frac{1}{4} \left(20t^{4}+16\right)+4\right\vert\right]+\frac{\pi}{8}=\frac{1}{4}\ln(8)+\frac{\pi}{8}=\boxed{\frac{3}{4}\ln(2)+\frac{\pi}{8}}\approx0.912559467$$

Note that you needed to take the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{x^4+t^4} }{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ earlier on in the problem.

Although my other answer was accepted by this point, I'd like to expand about the hint given in the above comments by @Did. This only shows that it converges, not what it converges to. Once you get to the step shown in those comments, use comparisons: $$0<\lim_{t\to 0}I(t)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1+x-(x^4+1)^{1/4}}{x(x^4+1)^{1/4}}dx<\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1+x-(x^4)^{1/4}}{x(x^4+1)^{1/4}}dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x(x^4+1)^{1/4}}dx<\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x(x^4)^{1/4}}dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}dx=1$$
which converges (and it should be easy for you to show/see/calculate that).